# How to create simple_list_item_2 List with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I can create simple_dropdown_item_1line, but I need to create 2 line list

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
ListView courses;
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    final DatabaseReference database = databaseReference.child(user.getUid());
.
.
.
courses = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.courseList);
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
courses.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
database.child("Lessons").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                list.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I create simple_dropdown_item_1line listView, and Everything works. But I can not create simple_dropdown_item_1line

Comment: There is no built-in 2 line dropdown as far as I know. Are you looking for `android.r.layout.simple_list_item_2`? (see the [Android reference docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html#simple_list_item_2))

Comment: @Developer Chingis   Have you or can you show us the JSON?   As mentioned above, there is no 2 line dropdown anywhere in your code so I'm assuming you are referring to listview that showcases 2 lines that drops down hence your listView and adapter.